# MySQLJDBCDataModel in Apache Mahout

Tags: mysql, apache, mahout

Can anyone post here an example of how to use the MySQLJDBCDataModel in Apache Mahout including the instantiating of a DataSource ?
I want to use the DataModel to generate Recommendations. A Databasetable (lets call it ratings) with user_id, task_id and rating already exists i just need to know how to access this information without creating my own implementation of DataModel.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use JNDI:

```
MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
dataSource.setServerName("my_database_host");
dataSource.setUser("my_user");
dataSource.setPassword("my_password");
dataSource.setDatabaseName("my_database_name");

JDBCDataModel dataModel = new MySQLJDBCDataModel(
    dataSource, "my_prefs_table", "my_user_column",
    "my_item_column", "my_pref_value_column", "my_timestamp_column");
```

Have a look in [MySQLJDBCDataModel](https://builds.apache.org/job/Mahout-Quality/javadoc/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/impl/model/jdbc/MySQLJDBCDataModel.html) for details...

Comment: Do  I really need to use DataSource for this? what if I am using hibernate? what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The class has a constructor that takes the name of the `DataSource`, or the `DataSource`. You just pass it the name (and optionally override the names of the table, columns, etc.) -- what else do you need here?

If you want to know how to look something up in JNDI, then it's as follows, but again this is done for you:

```
Context context = new InitialContext();
DataSource dataSource = 
    (DataSource) context.lookup("java:comp/env/" + dataSourceName);
context.close();
```

(You probably want to use `ReloadFromJDBCDataModel` too here.)

Comment: Thanks but what exactly is the DataSource Name ?
The name of the Database ?

Comment: Did you ever use this within a GWT application ?
Because whenever i instantiate the MySQLJDBCDataModel a window opens that tells me Communication error ...

Comment: I think you should read up on JNDI. No it is not the database name. It is a J2EE concept and I doubt you can use this in GWT.

Comment: So you doubt that i can use Apache Mahout within GWT at all ?

Comment: I don't know GWT well; it may support J2EE concepts like JNDI, but I didn't think so. But at best I am saying you may not be able to use MySQLJDBCDataModel. This != Mahout.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys !
It's really bad that GWT and Mahout don't work together. Me i had to integrate a Recommender System into an GWT Application for example ...

Comment: You are still misunderstanding. GWT may, or may not, support JNDI. If you need JNDI and it doesn't, you can't use GWT. This is nothing to do with Mahout. Mahout does *not* require JNDI, not even to use a database; you pass a `DataSource`. This again may or may not work in GWT; it is nothing to do with Mahout. *Mahout itself works just fine on GWT*. THis does not mean that Mahout plus any arbitrary third party dependencies do.

Comment: Hey, out of curiosity, what if I am using Hibernate as my orm, can I pass sessionFactory on this?

Comment: The method requires a `DataSource`, no.